# typecasting within dict of dicts

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, casting, floating-point

When parsing a file line by line, I generate a list of strings.  One of those strings is a number, so i'd like to typecast that as a float.

So

```
["PRO", "CCC", "4629.00"]
```

should be

```
["PRO", "CCC", 4629.00]
```

My parser reads the file line by line, but when I attempt to fill out my dict of dicts with the above list's [2] item as a float, like below:

```
fh = open("textfile_w_header","r")
def codon_preference_table_with_AA(fh):
    header = fh.readline()
    for line in fh:
        row = line.split()
        row[2] = float(row[2])
        myDict = {row[0]:{row[1]:row[2]}}
        print(myDict)
```

I get a value error:

```
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

Is there another way to typecast this innermost value as a float after making the dictionary?

Comment: Don't mix iteration (`for line in fh` and `readline()`). Use `next(fh)` instead to skip the header row.

Comment: use `next(fh)` instead of `fh.readline()`

Comment: This part I was not clear about: the header in the text file is something I do not want to make a dictionary out of, so I use readline to skip that first header line, then iterate through the rest to build my dictionary.  Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: whoa, how is this a duplicate?  did you read the question? its about typecasting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not following code?

```
line =  "PRO CCC 4629.00"
row = line.split()
f = float(row[2])
myDict = {row[0]:{row[1]:f}}
print(myDict)
```

it outputs.

```
{'PRO': {'CCC': 4629.0}}
```

Adopted to your code

```
fh = open("textfile_w_header","r")
def codon_preference_table_with_AA(fh):
    header = fh.readline()
    for line in fh:
        row = line.split()
        f = float(row[2])
        myDict = {row[0]:{row[1]:f}}
        print(myDict)
```

Comment: Thank you, Atilla.  Your solution worked perfectly for my needs.